# Why is this a 7th order circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, theory, passive-components

This is the circuit:

[image]

I saw it in a book. It said that this is a 7th order circuit.

From theory we know that the order of linear passive circuits is determined by the sum of capacitors and inductors, minus  the number of Inductor-nodes (a node where only inductors meet), minus the number of capacitor-meshes (a mesh that has only capacitors on it's branches).

This is my attempt to verify the order.

Capacitors + Inductors = 11

That component to the leftmost part of the schematic, judging from the way the book is illustrated previously, is just a complex electric impedance, so I believe that we can't do anything with that component. It doesn't count neither as capacitor, or inductor. It may contain 10 inductors inside but that's irrelevant, in order to find the order of the circuit (I'm not sure about that though).

Far to the right (my rightmost arrow) the inductor and capacitor can change their place without the circuit being affected in any way, so we have an inductor node.

Another inductor node exactly to the left of the previous one.

And one capacitor mesh, that I have marked to the left.

Therefore the order is 11 - 2 inductor nodes - 1 capacitor mesh = 8, not 7. So I'm clearly missing something here and I have no idea what it is. The way this problem was presented in the book seemed more like a trick question.

I will appreciate any help on this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the rule as you describe it, but why have you left the topmost and the rightmost capacitors out of your equation?

Comment: When did i say i left them out? They are here. I counted them all, 6 capacitors + 5 inductors equals 11. However i don't know whether they have a further role to play here. My guess is they don't. But who am i to say. What role do you think they play on the order?

Comment: where from are you taking the output?

Comment: From wherever you want to. I see only two input/output terminals though so if we consider this to be a two-port circuit then it can only be connected to an other two-port circuit from these terminals. Again, i'm not sure. I'm saying this because these are the only terminals that schematic has. I haven't found an answer to this trick question in a long time. So this could even be a mistake. Posting it on here is my last chance. If i get no answer here, i will go see the professor that wrote it and ask him myself. It's the professor in my university.

Comment: All the component can be reduced to one single impedance function, but asking about the the order is when you have a output and a feedback,Two port network cannot just have a single input port unless you trying to do a impedance matching, on the strip on a transmission line, the circuit can be resolved representing the capacitor as 1/s and inductor as s.

Comment: The problem is with the output point, the transfer function will vary,on the basis of selection of path put on G(s)open loop gain will vary, but the order is determined by the G(s)*H(s) hence just calculate the power of s, a inductor and capacitor may cancel each other's effect.

Comment: I meant to say that you didn't circle them as part of a mesh.

Comment: @jippie well they are not in a capacitor mesh are they?

Comment: As mentioned before I am not familiar with the rule you describe, but they seem to form a mesh. Leftmost capacitor, rightmost capacitor and topmost capacitor. Am I misunderstanding the technique?

Comment: @MaMba i believe taking the output to the rightmost part of the schematic is the most sensible thing to do here. This is what the professor always does. So considering this, if i try to take the transfer function or the impedance function by hand, considering there are 11 components (5 simple meshes) it will be very difficult. I can use software to help me, but i don't think this is the way to find out.

Comment: @jippie Just so that we are clear here, i meant a simple mesh, e.g. this circuit has three simple meshes https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Mesh_Analysis_Example2_TeX.svg/2000px-Mesh_Analysis_Example2_TeX.svg.png Considering this then i don't think these capacitors form a mesh as you said. I'm not from an english speaking country. What do you call these loops, or meshes?

Comment: @RestlessC0bra Using the circuit simulation what you can get is bode blot then calculate the dB rate of fall with semilog frequency each -20dB adds a pole, you can calculate using that, you can find the Code for MATLAB on the internet, Also what you can try using signal flow graph taking the output at the right most end, simplify the circuit in 1/s and s for cap/inductors then modify it in G(s)/1+G(s)H(s), and apply mason's gain formula, It is very easy to solve but essential thing is to know where the out put goes and identifying the feedback from there to the inputs, its better to use MATLAB

Comment: @MaMba Sure if i go about to do it analytically i guess i will find that. But i certainly don't think this was the purpose of the question. There must be a way to solve this by simple survey. It states in the book:"The order of ALL passive circuits can be calculated by overviewing them. Something that is rarely true for active and other types of circuits and filters".

Comment: @jippie actually you were right about that mesh i think. Sorry, i got confused and thought you meant something else. The answer was right in front of me but i couldn't picture it. I was stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Since I seem to understand how it works, I guess I've learned something too. Making note of this nice trick in my notebook.

Comment: The rule you describe isn't correct. Where did you get it? Consider the pi section of capacitors. It is a 2nd-order filter all but itself, as is the following T section of inductors, but your rule eliminates them both.

Comment: The rule is undoubtedly correct. It only applies for passive filters though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the mesh/loop which includes the left-most capacitor, the upper capacitor and the right-most capacitor. 11 reactive components - 2 inductor nodes - 2 cap meshes = 7.

If you're feeling up to the challenge you can also attempt to find the transfer function of the circuit (s-domain). The circuit order is whatever is higher: the order of the numerator polynomial or the order of the denominator polynomial.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra Not sure if it isn't a simple mesh as you can simply follow the outline of the diagram. In this case you would draw the vector to visualize current more conveniently at the outside of the circuit rather than on the inside of the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

A capacitor in series with a capacitor, or an inductor in parallel with an inductor, doesn't count. You have 2 instances of capacitor feeding capacitor, which drops the count to 7.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't get it. Where are the two series capacitors? And i actually didn't know this one rule you said, but i did the math on paper and i will guess why this rule is true. Is it because there is no \$s^2\$ term arising, in series capacitors, or shunt inductors? (when we do the analysis on the s-domain that is)